# Scrapy crawls only one page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have made a scrapy spider that I would like to crawl all the pages but it only crawls to the second page and then stops. 
It seems that within the `if next_page:` loop the url only changes to the second page and then sticks there. I think I am misunderstanding how http responses work because it seems to only grab the next page link on the starting page.

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import TriniCarsItem

class TCS(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "TCS"
    allowed_domains = ["TCS.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.TCS.com/database/featuredcarsList.php"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css("table > tr > td > a::attr('href')"):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield(scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents))
        next_page = response.css("body > table > tr > td > font > b > a::attr('href')")
        if next_page:
            url = response.urljoin(next_page[0].extract())
            print("THIS IS THE URL =----------------------------- " + url)
            yield(scrapy.Request(url, self.parse))

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//table[@width="543"]/tr/td/table/tr/td[2]/table'):
            item = TCSItem()
            item['id'] = sel.xpath('tr[1]/td[1]//text()').extract()
            item['make'] = sel.xpath('tr[3]/td[2]//text()').extract()
            item['model'] = sel.xpath('tr[4]/td[2]//text()').extract()
            item['year'] = sel.xpath('tr[5]/td[2]//text()').extract()
            item['colour'] = sel.xpath('tr[6]/td[2]//text()').extract()
            item['engine_size'] = sel.xpath('tr[7]/td[2]//text()').extract()
            item['mileage'] = sel.xpath('tr[8]/td[2]//text()').extract()
            item['transmission'] = sel.xpath('tr[9]/td[2]//text()').extract()
            item['features'] = sel.xpath('tr[11]/td[2]//text()').extract()
            item['additional_info'] = sel.xpath('tr[12]/td[2]//text()').extract()
            item['contact_name'] = sel.xpath('tr[14]/td[2]//text()').extract()
            item['contact_phone'] = sel.xpath('tr[15]/td[2]//text()').extract()
            item['contact_email'] = sel.xpath('tr[16]/td[2]//text()').extract()
            item['asking_price'] = sel.xpath('tr[17]/td[2]//text()').extract()
            item['date_added'] = sel.xpath('tr[19]/td[2]//text()').extract()
            item['page_views'] = sel.xpath('tr[20]/td[2]//text()').extract()
            #print(make, model, year, colour, engine_size, mileage, transmission, features, 
            #additional_info, contact_name, contact_phone, contact_email, asking_price, date_added, 
            #page_views)
            yield(item)
```

Comment: Does you `print` statement return the URL that you're expecting?

Comment: it does, but only the second page, it doesn't get the third page and so on

Comment: Does it print the same URL over and over again or only print once?

Comment: it jumps between two urls, the second page and the first page

Comment: Your css selector is probably not selecting what you're expecting it to

Comment: Your xpath selectors are really brittle, the css is not much better, are there no classes. id etc.. you can use to find what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the 2nd page the 1st link (the one you choose) is the one pointing to the previous page. Just send any links in order and let the de-duplicator cancel out any duplicates:

```
    if next_page:
        for i in next_page
            url = response.urljoin(i.extract())
            print("THIS IS THE URL =----------------------------- " + url)
            yield(scrapy.Request(url, self.parse))
```

P.S. In your case, consider also the significantly easier and way more massively parallel:

```
start_urls = [
    "http://www.trinicarsforsale.com/database/featuredcarsList.php?page=%d" % i for i in xrange(1, 460)]

def parse(self, response):
    return self.parse_dir_contents(response):
```

Comment: Thanks neverlastn, I tried your first suggestion and it didn't work but I agree that generating my urls with range would be simpler. Thanks!

Comment: Can you do a print of the URLs and try to see why it doesn't give you the correct results? It gave me page=3 URLs when I tried it on the 2nd page